# how to join three tables if many id pointing from one table to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am confused here about joining suppose I have three tables here student table, course table, teacher table

'student' table

```
std_Id    std_Name    course_Id   teacher_Id 
1         Amit         3           1
2         Yogesh       1           1
3         Pravin       3           2 
4         Nilay        1           3 
5         Abhijit      2           3
```

'course' table

```
course_Id   course_Name   std_Id   teacher_Id
1           JAVA           1        3
2           C#             1        3
3           C++            3        1
4           SAP            2        2
5           PYTHON         2        1
6          JAVASCRIPT      3        2
```

'teacher' table

```
teacher_Id  teacher_Name  std_Id  course_Id
1           Roy            1       1
2           John           2       1
3           Ben            1       3 
4           Renu           2       3
5           Ramesh         1       3
```

Here I am not giving any reference key so how  to join three tables I am giving query here

```
select Std_Name,Course_Name,Teacher_Name 
from   Student
inner join Course
        on ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._
inner join Teacher
        on ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._
```

As you can see I have three tables here so now I  want to see the students who have courses and teachers so let's look up here in the student table, we have std_id,course_id, and teacher_id and of course I want to show students who have courses them which column should be used here because in the student table we have std_id and course_id as well so which one should be used to join with course table std_id or course_id of student table and in the course table we have course_id and std_id as well so which column should be used here to join with student table and we also want to show teachers then student table also has teacher_id and course table also has teacher_id so which table's column should be used here to show teacher ?

So which condition should be used here to join three tables because here you can see many ids pointing from  one table to another table that`s why I was not able to understand this you know how to join these three tables and get the output please help me someone how can I solve this and   please let me know guys please give me answer and I have mentioned above what I want to show here in the output.

Comment: Why are you using those Unicode Characters for your SQL? T-SQL won't treat `` and `Student` as the same characters, so you will get errors.

Comment: not just bold here in the my question

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what you are trying to say in that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could use some formatting but from what I understand you want to join the 3 tables and that should look something like this:

```sql
select 
   s.Std_Name,
   c.Course_Name,
   t.Teacher_Name 
   from Student s
    inner join Course c on c.Course_ID = s.Course_ID
    inner join Teacher t on t.Course_ID = c.Course_ID
```

You should start using aliases (`from Student t`) as well as it makes it a lot easier and faster to join and reference tables.

Edit:

Think of the query above like this. A `Student` attends one (or more) `Courses` and each course has a `Teacher` that teaches it. Now the common thing between the `Student` and the `Course` is `Course_id` and that is why we joined it like this `s.Course_id = c.Course_id`. Now, we know that each `Course` has a `Teacher` that teaches it so the common thing between them is also `Course_id` thus the join is as follows `inner join t.Course_id = c.Course_id`.

Comment: hey but here many ids pointing so how can i know which column should be used?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a brief explanation. Please take a look at it.