# how to know which column should be used to join three tables if many id pointing from one table to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have three tables student table, course table, and teacher table something like this

'student' table

| std_id | std_name | course_id | teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ramesh | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Ganesh | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | Aadesh | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | Nilesh | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | Sonam | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | Abhi | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | Anil | 2 | 4 |

'course' table

| course_id | course_name | std_id | teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JAVA | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | JAVASCRIPT | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | VB.NET | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | C#.NET | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | PYTHON | 5 | 4 |
| 6 | SAP | 6 | 4 |
| 7 | C++ | 6 | 1 |

'teacher' table

| teacher_id | teacher_name | course_id | std_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roy | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Amit | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | John | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | Yogesh | 3 | 5 |
| 5 | Rocky | 3 | 1 |

so here I have given the three tables so now I want to show students who have the courses and teachers.

so here you can see in the 'student' table we have std_id and course_id and in the 'course' table we have course_id and std_id

so as you can see here in the student table we have std_id and course_id and in the course table we have course_id and std_id

so here which column should be used to join the student table with the course table?

because both tables have std_id and course_id and if I want to show students who have courses so which column should be used here to join the student table and the course table?

and here I also want to show teachers so here in the teacher table, we have teacher_id and course_id, and std_id here which table column should be used to join with the teacher table because the student table also has the  teacher_id and course table also has the teacher_id so here which table teacher_id should be used here to join with the teacher table?

please let me know guys how can I know which column should be used here to join?

Comment: I suggest taking the time to rewrite that *sentence* at the end of your question. It lacks any punctuation (apart from a single question mark (`?`) at the end), making it extremely difficult for anyone to read and understand what you are trying to say. I don't doubt it should be multiple sentences, and probably split into a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: *"hey please help me someone I got stuck here"* Please don't repost noise comments like this. I flagged your last comment to be removed as it didn't add anything, and neither does this one. You haven't even addressed my above comment by taken the time to [edit] your question, so why do you feel that others will take the time to help you, for free, in their own time?

Comment: Start by fixing the data structure. Presumably, a student can be enrolled in many courses. So it doesn't make any sense to have a course_id column in the student table. And visa-versa, remove the std_id column from the course table. There needs to be an additional table that holds the relationships between students and courses (i.e. course_x_student). In that same regard, a teacher really shouldn't have a direct relationship to the student so remove the std_id column from teacher. Then remove the course_id column from teacher because the course table already has a teacher_id column.

Comment: Why did you ask this question a second time? It was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74412177/2452207. Downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of importance going from left to right.

If your main focus is to show the students and which courses they take, then the Students table is on the left.  If your main focus is to show courses and which students take them, then the Courses table is on the left.  If your main focus is to show Teacher and what courses they teach, then the teacher table is on the left.

From there, use as many left joins as is necessary.  So, again, if your main focus is to show students and which courses they take, left outerjoin the Students table to the Courses table on Students.Course_ID = Courses.Course_ID.  Then you can left outer join the Courses table to the Teachers table on Course.Teacher_ID = Teacher.Teacher_ID.

Honestly, I think you can axe the Teacher_ID from the Students table, since the teacher is tied to a course and not a student.  Similarly, you can remove the Student_ID from both the Course and Teacher tables since that's eventually going to create multiple records.  The object of good table construction is really to reduce the possibility of 1:Many joins as much as you can.

Comment: thank you so much @johnny Bones you are the only man that has cleared my problem in very detail so thank you so much again

Answer (score 0):

Here's an SQL fiddle on how to join everything up. This is one way to do it, for an exact answer, you have to post a more precise question. As I said in my comment, the original data structure needs fixed. There is no need for every table to reference every other table. It is better to keep data segregated by purpose. For example, the teacher table shouldn't reference the student table unless there is some direct relationship between them. In this case, the teacher will have a logical relationship with the course they teach... but there is no reason to link to the student. The student is assigned to a course. The way you have the data structured, there can only be a 1-to-1 relationship between student and course (unless you duplicate a lot of data unnecessarily). I fixed the data structure and then created the `JOIN`s in a logical manner. I listed out all the courses, added who teaches the course, and then provide a list of students enrolled in the course.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a128/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  std_id int not null
  , std_name nvarchar(50) not null
  );
  
CREATE TABLE course (
  course_id int not null
  , course_name nvarchar(50) not null
  , teacher_id int null
);

CREATE TABLE teacher (
  teacher_id int not null
  , teacher_name nvarchar(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE course_x_student (
  uid int IDENTITY(1,1) not null
  , course_id int not null
  , std_id int not null
);

INSERT INTO student (std_id, std_name)
VALUES (1, 'Ramesh')
  , (2, 'Ganesh')
  , (3, 'Aadesh')
  , (4, 'Nilesh')
;
 
INSERT INTO teacher (teacher_id, teacher_name)
VALUES (1, 'Roy')
  , (2, 'Amit')
;

INSERT INTO course (course_id, course_name, teacher_id)
VALUES (1, 'JAVA', 1)
  , (2, 'JAVASCRIPT', 1)
  , (3, 'VB.NET' , 2)
;

INSERT INTO course_x_student (std_id, course_id)
VALUES (1, 1)
  , (2, 1)
  , (3, 3)
  , (4, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  c.*
  , t.teacher_name
  , STUFF((
      SELECT ',' + CAST(s.std_id as nvarchar) + ':' + s.std_name
      FROM student as s
        INNER JOIN course_x_student as cxs
          ON cxs.std_id = s.std_id
          AND cxs.course_id = c.course_id
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') as student_list
FROM course as c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN teacher as t
    ON t.teacher_id = c.teacher_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a128/3/0)**:

```
| course_id | course_name | teacher_id | teacher_name |      student_list |
|-----------|-------------|------------|--------------|-------------------|
|         1 |        JAVA |          1 |          Roy | 1:Ramesh,2:Ganesh |
|         2 |  JAVASCRIPT |          1 |          Roy |            (null) |
|         3 |      VB.NET |          2 |         Amit | 3:Aadesh,4:Nilesh |
```